# Do triggers have any performance impact on the stored procedure

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am creating a stored procedure that updates a single record. Based on that record very large number of records are recalculated and updated in another table. Currently I am using a trigger for this purpose. I just want to know if triggers have any performance issues that I should look into. Also does stored procedure returns the result after the trigger is completed or stored procedure returns result even if trigger is still running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

result of stored procedure depends  on the trigger statement

```
     BEFORE or  AFTER
```

regarding the performance it has both pros and cons, [refer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/magazine/cc164047%28en-us%29.aspx)